# add columns to datagridview usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i created an usercontrol for datagridview.
I set it as `gridview.autoGeneratecolumn = false;` in the usercontrol.

Question: How do i add columns to the usercontrol in my UI form?

- I cannot add default columns to the usercontrol as other UI form might not using the same columns.
- If i do not put `gridview.autoGeneratecolumn = false;`, then the auto generated columns will be showing my database columns name instead of the name i want to display to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on the property above

```
private List<string> _list = new List<string>();
private List<string> ColList
{
    get { return _list; }
    set { _list = value; }
}

private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn AddColumns(string Name)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            col.Name = Name;
            col.HeaderText = Name;
            col.HeaderCell.Style.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.NotSet;
            col.ToolTipText = Name;
            col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;            
            col.MinimumWidth = 80;
            col.DataPropertyName =Name;            
            return col;
        }
```

You can then loop through the ColumnList and Add and also set the basic properties for the columns

```
foreach(string s in ColList)
{ datagridview1.Columns.Add(AddColumns(s)); }
```

Comment: @belinq Did you find this useful ?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have replaced the `public List<string> _list = new List<string>();` with an array `public string[] Columns;`, Then it is easier for me to add ` baseGridView.Columns = new string[2]{"Name", "Password"};
           ` What do u think?

Answer (score 1):

You could always expose the Columns property of the datagridview as a property of your usercontrol.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    // This property will be visible in your usercontrols property window in the designer
    public DataGridViewColumnCollection Columns
    {
        get { return dataGridView1.Columns; }
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;          
    }
}
```

If you drop your usercontrol onto a form or another control, the Columns property will be accessible in the designer properties window.

Comment: Thank you, i did this below successfully. However is there a better way to extract or reduce this code ?  baseGridView.dgvMain.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
            baseGridView.dgvMain.Columns.Add("Password", "Password");
            baseGridView.dgvMain.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
            baseGridView.dgvMain.Columns["Password"].DataPropertyName = "Password";

            UserBindingSource.DataSource = Users;

Comment: How about passing a list for the columns, you can loop and add the columns

Comment: @belinq I have added an example .. please check,hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228046.aspx) on how to create columns with `gridview.autoGeneratecolumn` set to `false`